# Testing a component that uses usePathname hook in Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, next.js13

I am using the usePathname hook from next/navigation (Next.js 13) in one of my components, and I am struggling to mock it out.

In my application, the UserNavigationLayout (a layout.tsx file for the folder) renders the HeaderBar. HeaderBar just renders several Default Links. Default link contains the usePathname hook, which looks like:

```
"use client";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";
import localStyles from "./styles.module.css";
import { IDefaultLink } from "./DefaultLink.types.tsx";

export default function DefaultLink(props: IDefaultLink) {
  const { href, name, styleBox, styleBoxOpen } = props;
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <Link href={href} className={localStyles.link}>
      <li className={localStyles.noBullet}>
        <div className={pathname === href ? styleBoxOpen : styleBox}>
          {name}
        </div>
      </li>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

I am getting the following error:
"TypeError: (0 , _navigation.usePathname) is not a function" and is highlighting the render line.

```
import { expect, jest } from "@jest/globals";
import { cleanup, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { AuthContext } from "src/app/Context/AuthContext.tsx";
import * as mocks from "__mocks__/AuthContextMocks.ts";
import LoggedInPage from "./page.tsx";
import authContextPropsMock from "../../../../__mocks__/AuthContextMockFunc.ts";
import UserNavigationLayout from "./layout.tsx";

const mockUsePathname = jest.fn();

jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
  useRouter: () => ({
    push: jest.fn(),
    prefetch: jest.fn(),
  }),
  usePathname: () => mockUsePathname,
}));

describe("with usePathname", () => {
  it("should render the Logged In page when userRole is available in context", () => {

    render(
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...authContextPropsMock,
          firstName: mocks.firstNameMock1,
          lastName: mocks.lastNameMock1,
        }}
      >
        <UserNavigationLayout>
          <LoggedInPage />
        </UserNavigationLayout>
      </AuthContext.Provider>,
    );
  
  expect(screen.getByText("Initial Dashboard")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I am clearly missing something, but I don't know what!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your questions is hard to reproduce because you're referring to files which you did not show the content of. Having said that, could you update the mock to be: `usePathname: () => { return mockUsePathname(); }`, perhaps that'd solve the issue? Currently `usePathname` is a function that returns a function.

Answer (score 0):

you're on the right track. The only thing missing was the pathname.

Instead of:

```js
const mockUsePathname = jest.fn();
jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
  useRouter: () => ({
    push: jest.fn(),
    prefetch: jest.fn(),
  }),
  usePathname: () => mockUsePathname,
}))
```

You should do:

```js
jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
  usePathname: () => "localhost:3000/your-mocked-pathname",
}));
```

The error was because `usePathname` returns a string, but you were returning a function in your mock.